# (reference request) Simple(st) proof of construction of the probability measure on $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ with the product $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

For each $n\ge 1$, consider the fair coin probability space $(\Omega_i,\mathcal F_i, P_i)$ with $\mathcal \Omega_i=\{0,1\}$, sigma-algebra $\mathcal F_i = \{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, \Omega_i\}$ and $P_i(\{0\})=1/2 = P_i(\{1\})$.

Let $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}=\prod_i \Omega_i$ be the set of binary sequences, and let $\mathcal F$ be the product $\sigma$-algebra, which is as usual the $\sigma$-algebra generated by sets of the form $\prod_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ where $A_i\subset \{0,1\}$ and $|A_i|=1$ only for finitely many $i$.

I am looking for a reference for a simple self-contained proof of the construction of the product probability measure on $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$,

- without relying on extension theorems, and
- without relying on Tonelli's theorem either.

One paper cited in a related question is "A Proof of the Existence of Infinite Product Probability Measures" by Sadahiro Saeki. This paper does not rely on Tonelli theorem.

I am wondering if the very simple structure of $\Omega$ here (countable product, each $\Omega_i$ with cardinality 2) allows for a simple proof that bypasses the more general arguments used in extension theorems. The context is for teaching probability on a rigourous footing with $\sigma$-algebras but without the full measure theoretic machinery of extension theorems: For most probability problems before stochastic processes, one only requires a countable sequence of independent real random variables with prescribed distribution, and $\Omega$ above is sufficiently rich for that purpose.

Comment: If you have Lebesgue measure constructed, then I think the binary digits of a uniform $X \in [0, 1]$ has your desired distribution. Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ can be constructed using Caratheodorys extension theorem, or from scratch. This approach will probably need the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem though, for proving that $X$ has the desired distribution (Tonelli's theorem is a consequence of $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem too).

Comment: My hope is to have a simple self-contained proof that bypasses Caratheodorys extension theorem for $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$. And then (the other way around compared to what the previous comment mentions), to obtain the Lebesgue measure on [0,1] as a consequence of the probability measure on $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$. On the other hand, I am fine with assuming the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem.

Comment: I know how to get finite products of probability transition kernels using $\pi - \lambda$. I don't know of a simple way to bootstrap from finite dimensional to countable, other than using the construction from Caratheodory.